# Turn off local monitor when TightVNC connection is active

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, display, tightvnc

TightVNC does not have an option to turn off (or stand-by) the monitor when a client is remotely administering the server. Is there any way to keep the windows system from waking the monitor when remotely connecting this way, or to manually standby the monitor , where it would not wake back up from the input commands?

I want the monitor to respond and wake only via the local input. I need some way to keep it in stand-by, or put it in stand-by when working it remotly using TightVNC?

I have tried  turning off monitor via windows power management (or using utilities like wizmo monoff or nircmd monitor off) it turns back on at first remote input (keyboard or mouse).

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research. Here are a few suggestions on how to properly ask this type of question.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve was described too, anyway I try to specify more precisely. I need to turn off the local monitor while remote managing the pc and let it remains off also when using remote input (keyboard or mouse). If I turn off monitor via windows power management (or using utilities like wizmo monoff or nircmd monitor off) it turn on at first remote input (keyboard or mouse). I want it to be wakened up only by local input.